# How do i create a UItableViewContoller with Static Cells and insert a UITableView with Prototype Cell into one of those Static Cells?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, nested

1. is it possible to accomplish? even if it's not recommended
2. if it is possible, how do i do it exactly?

if you know a way - please elaborate as much as possible :)

Im working on Swift, so Obj-C doesn't really help

Thank you to all those who take the time to read and answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First starting with the storyboard here is the hierarchy of tableViewController. see the below image.

[image]

after that create a UITableViewCell class to hold the second table view and assign that class to second table view cell. as below.

```
import UIKit
class tableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dynamicCell")!
         cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
         return cell
    }
}
```

[image]

and then in tableViewController cellForRow method initialize both the cell and return the cell as required.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return 50
    } else {
        return 200
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("staticCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell")! as! tableTableViewCell
        return cell
    }

    // Configure the cell...
}
```

That's It. here you Go. Here is the output of the above code.

[image]

You can see that first "cell 1" is a static cell and below that in second cell there is another tableView showing the number 0-4 means another 5 cell of second tableview in cell 2.

Comment: sorry for taking long to mark this as the right answer. had to test it before i mark - and it works like charm. Thank you for your time and for the very good answer post :)